# Wondering if averaging datapoints by a set number of observations is a valid way to aggregate data in a scatterplot

Tags: r, distributions, aggregation

So essentially the problem I have is this: I've created an economics simulation which, among other things, tracks the profit rates and capital intensity of all the firms over the course of the simulation [image: unaggregated data]. The trouble is, which you can see from the scatterplot of these two variables, is how dense and difficult to read it is.

A solution I came up for this was to sort the variables according to increasing capital intensity, divide them up into 100 equal sized buckets, and get the average of each variable for each bucket of observations. Which produces this much more readable graph and much more obvious negative linear regression the literature has.[image] My question: is this a valid way of aggregating the data? Does this misrepresent the distribution of the data in some crucial way?

EDIT: for reference here's the R code I used to aggregate it

```
dfPC<-data.frame(proRateDis[order(capIn)], capIn[order(capIn)])
divSize<-100

divCount<-rep(1:divSize, ceiling(length(dfPC$capIn)/divSize))
divCount<-sort(divCount)
dfPC$divCount<-divCount[1:length(dfPC$capIn)]
mPC<-matrix(nrow = divSize, ncol = 3)
mPC[,1]<-1:divSize
for (dC in (1:divSize) ) 
  {
  mPC[dC, 2]<-sum(dfPC$proRateDis.order.capIn..[dfPC$divCount==dC])/sum(dfPC$divCount==dC)
  mPC[dC, 3]<-sum(dfPC$capIn.order.capIn..[dfPC$divCount==dC])/sum(dfPC$divCount==dC)
}

plot(mPC[,2], mPC[,3], xlab = "Capital Intensity", ylab = "Profit Rate")
abline(lm(mPC[,3] ~ mPC[,2]))
```

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because your description is too vague.  How exactly do you "divide" up these *bivariate* data?  What exactly is a "bucket"? Which variable(s) are determined by any such bucket? What kind of average do you use within each bucket? There exist many solutions to this plotting problem, btw, including partial transparency, hex plots, sunflower plots, various forms of smoothing, and much more.

Comment: Maybe this would be illustrative @whuber I added the R code to the post

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me. You are effectively replacing the data by a local regression.(See eg loess). Whether this is sensible depends on what you want to use the simulated data for. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Comment: @seanv507 It would *seem* to be a local regression, but the shape of the result doesn't look like it: in places it looks like a bivalent function, which isn't possible for a local regression.

Comment: A local regression might actually make more sense than what I'm doing right now, as it's more continuous and would create a smoother representation rather than averaging in discrete chunks. I'll try that.

Comment: hmm, actually I'm not sure that looks very useful either https://imgur.com/FEeFNW0

Comment: That image does not show a local regression.  Use a GAM or Loess smooth or even a simple windowed median.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

I don't think your method is good, at least, not for these data. For one thing, your original graph had outliers (one very extreme) which your method totally obscures. That is *not* a good thing.

A couple of ideas:

Change the symbol for the dots to something like  .   This is easy in R, just putting `pch = .` in the appropriate spot should work.

Another issue that makes your graph hard to read is the shape. I'm no expert on economics, but, often, taking logs makes sense for economics data. That ought to make your graph easier to read, but I don't know if it is a good idea (in R, you can change the axes to log type).

Or, you can divide the X-axis variable into bins and make box plots of the y axis variable in each bin.

I wrote a paper for a SAS conference called ["Scatterplots: Basics, enhancements, problems and solutions"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279188186_Scatterplots_Basics_enhancements_problems_and_solutions) (it's available in other places, too).  It uses SAS, not R, but the ideas are pretty easy to translate.

Comment: Unfortunately there's too many datapoints that are at or below zero for a log scale to be effective, that's one of the first things I tried.

Comment: That is a problem.  Some people (not me, but some people) will add a very small number to all the 0's. You can try with different small numbers and see what works. 

Or you could take square roots.

Comment: Here's what it looks like with the pch = ".", I don't think it's much of an improvement: https://imgur.com/NWNiZ3x  . As for the outliers, keep in mind this data is the result of a stochastic simulation, i would still like to be able to characterize an overall distribution even given outliers in the tails which are somewhat likely.

Comment: Maybe I could add two bars, one for each axis, to each dot indicating the variance for each variable.